# Trigger a test http request

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express

For unit testing purposes I want to trigger a fake http request in expressjs to my routes to test how each respond. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You can use Superfish and Mocha to do this fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger a real request. it will not use any bandwidth since its on the same machine

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'example.com',
    path: '/test'
};

http.request(options).end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Request.js is the most common way to send requests with node.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
  }
})
```